# Make changes in a webp image used as bitmap (google map)

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-mapview, android-bitmap, android-image

I have the following code:

```
private BitmapDescriptor getMapIcon() {  
  int resourceId = R.drawable.myimage;  
  return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(resourceId);  
}  
...  
MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();  
....
markerOptions.icon(getMapIcon());  
....  
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

So this works and displays the custom marker.
`R.drawable.myimage` is a webp image.
I was wondering if I wanted to make some changes to the image (e.g. add some border or background) is there another way e.g. to wrap it in another layout and still be able to use `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource`?

Answer (score 0):

you can convert it to a Bitmap and then use canvas to draw border or modify in any way you think is right.

Comment: Is that the only way? Could I have some other resource xml file that can do that too? E.g. some `layer-list` or something like that?

Comment: yeah you can use layer-list as well i thought you wanted to modify this after loading the drawable in your class. If that's not the caseuse layer-list.

Comment: What is `caseuse layer-list`?

Comment: Sorry, It's not caseuse it's "case use".